# Image from relative path in Jupyter Markdown cell not rendering on Github

Tags: image, github, jupyter-notebook, markdown, rendering

I have a Github repository with the following directory structure:

```
README.md
imgs/
    example.jpg
notebooks/
    notebook.ipynb
```

I would like to embed `example.jpg` to a Markdown cell of `notebook.ipynb`. My attempt was to use

```
![Image](../imgs/example.jpg)
```

Although this renders fine locally, when I upload things to Github, I only see a broken link and the text description `Image`. There are numerous suggestions online on how to address this problem but none of them worked for this case. Is this not feasible using relative paths or am I missing something?

Unfortunately, I cannot share the repository link because it's private, but I hope that my description of it gives all the necessary information.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `![Python logo](../imgs/python-logo.png)` works for me, both locally and on GitHub. It took a few minutes for GitHub to render the first time, but it does work. Are you still having trouble with it?

Comment: @Chris You are absolutely right. I tested this with both a private and a public repository and it works as you say. For some strange reason the problem persists on the original repository. I am wondering if it has to do with the fact that the repository is under an Organization and not under my personal account.

Comment: Okay. I'm voting to close as not reproducible. Maybe try pushing that same project to a new repo on GitHub, just to see what happens?

Comment: I have the same problem. There are no problems in my public repositories, but images do not appear in Markdown cells if the IPYNB file is in a private repository.